# How to create an inverted index when I've already tokenized my file?

Tags: c++, vector, unordered-map, inverted-index

I'm trying to create an inverted index. I'm reading the lines of a text file, the text file has in the first position of each line the id of a document `docId` and the rest of the line has keywords about this document.
 In order to create an inverted index, I first have to tokenize this text file. I did it with a function I wrote, and I store every word in a vector. My only gripe is that I also store the `docId` as a string in the vector. Here is the header of the tokenize function if you need it:

```
void tokenize(string& s, char c, vector<string>& v)
```

Now after tokenizing the file I have to create a function that puts every word in a map, i'm thinking of using an unordered map, in the map every word appears one time. I also have to somehow store the frequency of the word somewhere. I thought that using the `docId` as a key in the map would be a good idea but then I realized that I can only have one `docId` which will show me the word, while in my text file a `docId` has more than one words.

So, how am I going to solve this problem? Where should I begin?

Comment: Begin by writing some code after that you can get help with the problems you face. Perhaps you should also provide the code for tokenize(). Btw: There must be some more info about the map! For sure it sounds as if the words shall be the key but which value shall it hold? Perhaps that could be a count of the number of times a specific word was found, e.g. `map<string, unsigned>`

Answer (score 1):

What a mess of a question.  Breaking it down, if I understand correctly you have:

```
doc1 word1a word1b word1c word1d
doc2 word2a word2b word2c
...
```

You want mappings from words to documents and vice versa.  It's hard to tell from your question whether your talk of word "frequency" reflects the same word being a keyword for multiple documents, or whether the description you have of your file format failed to incorporate a needed count for repetitions within each file.  Assuming the former:

```
if (std::ifstream f(filename))
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<string>> words_in_doc;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<string>> docs_containing_word;
    std::string line;
    while (getline(f, line))
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        std::string docid, word;
        if (line >> docid)
            while (line >> word)
            {
                words_in_doc[docid].push_back(word);
                docs_containing_word[word].push_back(docid);
            }
    }
    // do whatever with your data/indices...
}
else
    std::cerr << "unable to open input file\n";
```